# Why does my appscript function stop working when adding more arguments?

Tags: javascript, python, excel

I am trying to implement the following python code as a function for use in google sheets:

```
def districttownlookup(district,category,index,range):
location = 0
range_t = list(map(list, zip(*range)))
for item in range_t[0]:
if item.contains(category):
        location = range_t[0].index(item)
        break
towns = []
for row in range_t:
    if district == row[location]:
        towns.append(row[index - 1])
return towns
```

I don't know javascript but I believe this is the equivalent code in JS:

```
function districttownlookup(district, category, index, range) {
  var location = 0, range_t = [], towns = [];
  range_t = Object.keys(range[0]).map(function (c) { return range.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
  for (const item of range_t[0]) {
    if (item.includes(category)) {
      location = range_t[0].indexOf(item);
      break;
    }
  }

  for (const row of range_t) {
    if (district == row[location]) {
      towns.push(row[index - 1]);
    }
  }

  return towns;
}
```

For some reason, this doesn't work when I use it in Google Sheets, so I created another function to test each part. I started with just the part of the code that transposes the array selection:

```
function myFunction(range) {
  range_t = Object.keys(range[0]).map(function (c) { return range.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
  return range_t
}
```

This DOES work. However, once I change it to

```
function myFunction(district, category, index, range) {
  range_t = Object.keys(range[0]).map(function (c) { return range.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
  return range_t
}
```

I get a "formula parse" error in sheets, even though the the value I am providing for the range parameter in sheets is the same for both functions. Maybe the issue is the unused arguments? In which case, there must be an error in the code for the districttownlookup function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am implementing my custom function in sheets as districttownlookup(A2,'State Senate',2,Sheet2!A2:B23), where A2 is a cell containing 'Norfolk and Plymouth', and Sheet2!A2:B23 is a range where A2 is a cell containing 'Town', A3:A23 are cells containing various strings representing towns, B2 is a cell containing 'State Senate District', and B3:B23 are cells each containing 'Norfolk and Plymouth'.

Edit 2: I figured out a better way to do it using just google sheets functions.

Comment: From `I get a "formula parse" error in sheets`, I thought that you might be using your script as a custom function. If my guessing is correct, can you provide your sample formula as the custom function you put into a cell? If you are not using your showing script as a custom function, can you provide the sample value of the arguments?

Comment: @Tanaike, I added a description of its implementation in sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Edit 2: I figured out a better way to do it using just google sheets functions.`, I'm glad your issue was resolved.